# What gulp-plugin can be used to convert jpg/png to progressive/interlaced?

Tags: gulp, png, jpeg, image-optimization, gulp-imagemin

I'm using gulp-imagemin, but i want to not only minify images, but make them progressive/interlaced. What tool can be used for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typed "gulp image progressive" into Google and [gulp-image-optimization](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-image-optimization) was the first result. Here's a direct copy/paste of the example on that page:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var imageop = require('gulp-image-optimization');

gulp.task('images', function(cb) {
    gulp.src(['src/**/*.png','src/**/*.jpg','src/**/*.gif','src/**/*.jpeg']).pipe(imageop({
        optimizationLevel: 5,
        progressive: true,
        interlaced: true
    })).pipe(gulp.dest('public/images')).on('end', cb).on('error', cb);
});
```

Comment: This plugin is outdated: "2 years ago"

Comment: Great. Did you try it? It's often helpful to list the things you've already tried because after reading your post I'm assuming you've tried nothing... including Google.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to said about this. It seems that there is no another plugin for this task.

Comment: I am also searching for "progressive images with gulp" not finding anything.